# Is there a project euler equivalent that stresses computer science rather than mathematics?

Tags: computer-science

I've been doing project Euler for a few days, and I have to admit it's quite fun. However, it would be good if there were something that were more focused on computer science rather than on mathematics. Something like this would be interesting for practicing algorithms and data structures, such as in preparing for coding interviews.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might enjoy [Programming Praxis](http://programmingpraxis.com), which provides a collection of etudes, updated weekly, for the education and enjoyment of the savvy programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this on another SO question - http://www.scs.stanford.edu/10wi-cs140/pintos/pintos.html

It basically takes you through this simplified OS, touching on key components of an OS, how they are implemented in Pintos, and how to modify and customize them. It's a great way to learn system internals programming and basically a free Level 300 "Operating Systems" university course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has answered this, but...

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/

You submit the code, and it tells you if you succeeded at solving the problems for their input or not.  Keeps track of your successes, failures, submissions, ranking...similar to Project Euler.

Sadly (in my opinion) the number/type of languages it accepts for submissions is somewhat limited (C, C++, Java, Pascal).  Still, the number and organization of the projects is incredibly good, and you really can get pushed around on some concepts.